# in a public/private network deployment of MAAS + Openstack why does MAAS need to know about the public network?

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

Mainly to  [@andreas](https://askubuntu.com/users/181622/andreas)  who wrote the guide [MAAS network layouts for the Landscape Autopilot](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/10/maas-network-layouts-for-the-landscape-autopilot/)

You state:
`MAAS only manages the private network, for which it will setup DNS and DHCP, but it has to know about the public one.`

Why does the MAAS need to know about the public network if I'm planning on *only* using the public network via Openstack?

Answer (score 0):

One instance where this is required is when configuring Neutron OpenVSwitch within Autopilot as you will need to select your 'provider' network. That information is pulled from MAAS, therefore, it needs to be defined within MAAS.